# jquery image slider on click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

how to call this id with click event in jquery I mean I want to load the image of click this id.

My code

```
$("#carousel-selector-1").click(function(){

              $(".first").hide(); // hide first image showing in this class
              $("#carousel-selector-1").show(); // now showup this image
             <!-- <a class="" id="carousel-selector-1"><img src="abc.jpg"></a> --> // Want to load
    });
```

Please guide how to correct it.

Error in jQuery

Getting error in jquery Please suggest

```
$("#carousel-selector-1").click(function(){

              $(".first").hide();
              $("#carousel-selector-3").html("");
        var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.jpg|.jpeg|.gif|.png|.bmp)$/;
        if (regex.test($(this).val().toLowerCase())) {
            if ($.browser.msie && parseFloat(jQuery.browser.version) <= 9.0) {
                $("#carousel-selector-3").show();
                $("#carousel-selector-3")[0].filters.item("DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader").src = $(this).val();
            }
            else {
                if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
                    $("#carousel-selector-3").show();
                    $("#carousel-selector-3").append("<img />");
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                        $("#carousel-selector-3 img").attr("src", e.target.result);
                    }
                    reader.readAsDataURL($(this)[0].files[0]);
                } else {
                    alert("This browser does not support FileReader.");
                }
            }
        } else {
            alert("Please upload a valid image file.");
        }

    });
```

getting the error in Please upload a valid image file can you please suggest the process that need to change

Comment: Don't hide first image..hide all the image through class selector

Comment: its not the first image it is the class name of first that i am hiding

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle, so we can test it please? jsfiddle.net